# Difference between opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter and the OpenTelemetry support in micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer, open-telemetry-java, micrometer-oltp

I am trying to find out the easiest and most reliable way to enable OpenTelemetry observability in SpringBoot. On one hand we have the OpenTelemetry micrometer support for [metrics](https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/implementations/otlp.html) and [tracing](https://docs.micrometer.io/tracing/reference/tracers.html). Tracing requires an exporter provided by OTEL as well:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

On the other hand, we have the official [OpenTelemetry starter dependency `opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter`](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/spring-boot/#opentelemetry-starter-dependency) which does autoconfiguration, instrumentation and brings several additional dependencies not included by default in SpringBoot.

To the best of my knowledge there is some overlapping in both solutions as they do instrumentation to some degree, but I would like to know the following:

1. What offers `opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter` that micrometer + `opentelemetry-exporter-otlp` does not already have.
2. In which scenarios I would choose `opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter` instead of the micrometer support.