Does OpenTelemetry autoconfiguration uses micrometer behind the scenes?
I'm looking at the Spring-Boot starter (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/zero-code/java/spring-boot-starter/getting-started/) and it's not clear to me if it uses micrometer and its otlp exporter in the background, does it?

No, it's a completely different code base - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78185793/difference-between-opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter-and-the-opentelemetry-suppo.
